# Creating pages on feature activation

Tags: page-layout, solution-package

Is it possible to add an ASPX page from my WSP to the Site Pages library, or do I have to do this via code (IE: Create the page as a list item and add web parts manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
    string pageName = "MyCustomPage.aspx";
    PageLayout[] pageLayouts = publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts();
    PageLayout currPageLayout = pageLayouts[0];
    PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();
    PublishingPage newPage = pages.Add(pageName, currPageLayout);
    newPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = "This is my content";
    newPage.ListItem.Update();
    newPage.Update();
    newPage.CheckIn("This is just a comment");
}
```

What the above code does is, when the feature (Web scoped) is activated it creates an ASPX page in `Pages` Library. The `Pages` library is created you activate `SharePoint Server Publishing` feature in your Site. Above code snippet has been taken from [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/17/create-publishing-pages-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/).